# Share the same UI for two subclasses in Obj-C/Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

I have a `ViewControllerA`, and its UI layout is designed in the Interface Builder (storyboard).

`ViewControllerA` has two concrete subclasses, `ViewControllerB1` and `ViewControllerB2`; they have the same UI with its superclass `ViewControllerA`, but run with different logic.

How can I create two different concrete classes but they share the same UI with storyboard in which you must indicate the view controller's class?

Comment: Could you use an xib file?

Comment: Yes, just wondering about storyboard.

Comment: Because I'm handling an existing project created by other guys, and they created a static table view using storyboard. Now, it has different behaviors  for circumstances, so I need to subclass it for different logic but using the same UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately storyboard doesn't support subclassing.
You should create delegate in `ViewControllerA` for different logic.